# flutter realtime database 'InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' this error

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I get this error. I'm very angry.

```
Stream<List<TestModel>> awayStream() async* {
List<TestModel> retVal = <TestModel>[];
_categoryCollectionReferance.once().then((DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  print(dataSnapshot.value);
  retVal.add(TestModel.fromJson(dataSnapshot.value));
  return retVal;
});}
```

Error : `[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'`

```
print(dataSnapshot.value); -- this perfectly working.
```

But I cant add on the list.
Here is the my model codes;

```
TestModel.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
awayCurrentUser = dataSnapshot.value['awayCurrentUser'] ?? 0;
awayDate = dataSnapshot.value['awayDate'] ?? 0;
awayID = dataSnapshot.value['awayID'] ?? '';
awayMaxUser = dataSnapshot.value['awayMaxUser'] ?? 0;
awayPhotoUrl = dataSnapshot.value['awayPhotoUrl'] ?? '';
awayPrice = dataSnapshot.value['awayPrice'] ?? 0;
awayTitle = dataSnapshot.value['awayTitle'] ?? '';
awayUserPrice = dataSnapshot.value['awayUserPrice'] ?? 0;
awayWinner = dataSnapshot.value['awayWinner'] ?? '';
awayWinnerName = dataSnapshot.value['awayWinnerName'] ?? '';
isEnabled = dataSnapshot.value['isEnabled'] ?? true;
isFinished = dataSnapshot.value['isFinished'] ?? false;
isStatus = dataSnapshot.value['isStatus'] ?? true;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

it is because the datasnapShot is not a 'Map<String, dynamic>' type or its subtype decode it before accessing the inner objects

try like this

```
dataSnapshotDecoded=json.decode(dataSnapshot.value);

 retVal.add(TestModel.fromJson(dataSnapshotDecoded))
```

Comment: I solved this problem. I have a new question. When I change data on database, cant updating data list.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, no `json.decode()` or `jsonDecode()` or `json.decode(json.encode())` methods saw in other answers helped me, this is how I solved it :

```
final value = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value! as Map<Object?, Object?>);
```